# Generation of n terms that sums to a specific value?

Tags: statistics, combinations, integer-partitions

I'm about to conduct an integer program where I am to transport some products from different cities to docks and refinement stations. I am however required to work with simulated data where I only have total demand to "match" the supplies to. There are however different product types which demands are specified as a percentage of the total demand. It is not specified how the supplies of these product types are spread, and it is my task to find these.

Thus, is there a mathematical approach to find a specified amount of terms, n (corresponding to the supply locations) that sums to a specified value (the percantage of the total demand for that specific product type)? It is not sufficient to assume a evenly distributed supply throughout every origin.

I hope anyone has any idea of some theorem, or method of finding these combinations of terms.

EDIT: If one has any tips regarding if there are any good tags to add, please let me know. I'm not quite sure into what mathematical field this question is suitable for.

Also, tips regarding algorithms are also welcome.

EDIT: I've found out that integer partitioning may be associated with these kinds of problems. I'm trying to read as much as I can in the subject to find a suitable algorithm. Any tips or hints regarding algorithms, or if some special type of integer partitioning may be applicable is very helpful. Or if it can be solved with other techqnicues.

Thanks in advance
Cenderze

Comment: I'd advise you to hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: How come? Are there no theories for this purpose?

Comment: If you're in the business of transporting products to docks, your company can afford to hire a mathematical consultant to solve its problems.

Comment: The project is to solve such a project. I am however conducting the survey as a student with no financial aid and very limited help from the companies associated (the reason I'm working with simulated data is due to the companies having too little time to provide actual data).

Comment: Is there no one on the faculty of your university you can talk to?

Comment: Say for example, a specific product type's demand is 10 units and it has 3 supply locations. Are you then trying to find integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ where $x_i$ is the supply from the $i$th location?

Comment: I want to simulate the supply from a set of origins, yes. I want some to have a supply of 0, and the sum of the x variables to be a specific value, corresponding to a percentage of the total demand for that particular product. The terms must be integer.

Comment: Could [this](http://ideone.com/62bir1) program be useful? It uses [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find integer solutions to $\sum_{i=0}^{n}w_ix_i = S$. BTW, prefix your response with "@username" so that "username" gets a notification.