# Summation on multiplication of two numbers that equal to a specified sum

Tags: number-theory, combinations

Suppose I have N terms like $a_ix_i$ and coefficient $x$ is a constant for each $i$. How should I find all combinations of $a_i$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^Na_ix_i=S$?
$a_i\in \{0,1,2,...,\}$ $x_i\in \{2,1,6,.,3\}$

How about a matrix like 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}x_{11}       & b_{12}x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & c_{1,n}x_{1n} \\
    a_{21}x_{21}       & b_{22}x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & c_{2,n}x_{2n} \\
\\
    a_{d1}x_{d1}       & b_{d2}x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots c_{d,n}& x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
that I have to select one term from each columns to sums to $S$?
Any specific algorithm or optimization model for these problems?
Any hint what should I looking for?
Thanks

**Edit: To anyone who faces the same problem. Comments in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801935/generation-of-n-terms-that-sums-to-a-specific-value?rq=1) question helped me achieve what I wanted.**

Comment: Do you mean that the $x_i$ are constants?

Comment: Yes for each term that exist I have a constant x . for example for $x_1=5, x_3=1$ I add it to my question. Thanks